# VBA: Range.Find nested in another Range.Find

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my code, I'm splitting a word document into many using  `Range.Find` to select a body of text (startoftext*endoftext) and then saving it. Within this selected body of text, I'm trying to use a nested 'Range.Find' call to search the selected body of text for the bolded header and use it as the SaveAs[FileName].

With the current code, everything works except the nested `Range.Text` returns all text within the initial set range.

```
Sub DocSplitter()

Dim R As Range
Dim inR As Range
Set R = ActiveDocument.Range.Duplicate
Dim name As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With R.Find
    .Text = "^m*^l^t^l" ' <- Copies all text from ^m to "^l^t^l"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    While .Execute
        Set inR = R.Duplicate '<- Setting Range equal to selected text range
        With inR.Find
            .Format = True
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Text = "^13([0-9]).([0-9])*^13^13" '<- Selecting header within
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
        End With
        CopyAndSave R, inR
    Wend
End With
R.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
R.End = R.Parent.Range.End
CopyAndSave R, inR

End Sub




Static Sub CopyAndSave(R As Range, inR As Range)
Dim D As Document
Dim Count As Long
Count = Count + 1
R.Copy
Set D = Documents.Add
D.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
D.SaveAs R.Parent.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
inR.Text, wdFormatFilteredHTML '<-- File Name ERROR: Too long
D.Close

End Sub
```

so inR.Text returns the entire text selected by R.Find.Execute.
Any Ideas?

Edit: I updated `Set inR = R.Duplicate`, thanks for that catch. My problem turned out to be a formatting issue with the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set one Range to another Range both objects point to the exact same thing. This is different from everything else we use in VBA, where the second object becomes an independant copy of the first.

In order to create a second Range based on another, but independent of it you need the`Duplicate` property. So:

```
Set inR = R.Duplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set Set inR = R and then execute the find command on inR, R will also change. This is unlike Excel. If you know the C language, it helps to think of a range variable as being a pointer. Using Set inR = R means that both variables point to the same thing; altering one, alters the other.

One way to work around that is to store R.Start and R.End as integers before searching and then, after you complete your inner search, you can recreate R from activedocument.Range(r.Start,r.End).

Comment: Good find, I used `Set inR = R.Duplicate`, but that did not fix my problem. inR still covers the entire range of R after `.execute`. I'm thinking the problem is coming from using and saving `.execute` properly.